# Cómo saber si se han mostrado las imágenes devueltas por ajax

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo una página en la que estoy rellenando un **div** a partir del código **html**  generado por un **php** al que llamo por **ajax**.

Este div se rellena con varias imágenes que van dentro de otros divs, etc. Simplificando mi problema, necesito que a todas les asigne la misma altura. Tras la carga calculo la altura de cada imagen, me quedo con la mayor y la asigno a todas las imágenes.

El problema es que aunque ejecute esta función `AjustarAlturaImagenesInterior` en el complete después de asignar el resultado al div, parece que aún las imágenes no están "dibujadas" porque no siempre me devuelve su altura (en algunos casos sigue a 0).

Para salir del paso estoy poniendo un Timeout antes de llamar a la función que obtiene la altura máxima, pero esto es un poco "chapuza" porque a veces puede necesitar mas tiempo, etc.

¿Cómo podría saber cuando ha pintado realmente todo el html devuelto para asegurarme que me va a devolver las alturas correctamente?

Adjunto parte de mi código:

```
function BuscarInteriores(numpage) {
  var formato=$("#selFormatoInterior option:selected").val();
  var tamaño=$("#selTamañoInterior option:selected").val();
  $.ajax({
    url: 'consultas/BuscarInterioresCondicionR.php',
    type: 'get',
    data:{'formato':formato,'tamaño':tamaño,'page':numpage},
    success: function (results) {
      $('#divDrchoInteriores').addClass("transparente");
      $('#divDrchoInteriores').html(results);
       /*para que no se vea antes de redimensionar*/
      setTimeout(function(){
        AsignarEventosaInteriores();
        AjustarAlturaImagenesInterior();
        AjustarAlturaCuadroImagenesInterior();
        $('#divDrchoInteriores').removeClass("transparente");
      }, 500);

    },
    error: function(err){
      alert(err);
    }
  });
}
```

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 2):

Al final he encontrado la solución en la respuesta de Daniel Howard.
[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774746/jquery-ajax-wait-until-all-images-are-loaded).

MI código ha quedado  así:

```
 $('#divDrchoInteriores').html(results).imagesLoaded().then(function(){
                   //   $('#divDrchoInteriores').html(results).promise().done(function(){   
                        AsignarEventosaInteriores();
                        AjustarAlturaImagenesInterior();
                        AjustarAlturaCuadroImagenesInterior();
                        $('#divDrchoInteriores').removeClass("transparente");  
                    });

// Fn to allow an event to fire after all images are loaded
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774746/jquery-ajax-wait-until-all-images-are-loaded
$.fn.imagesLoaded = function () {
    // get all the images (excluding those with no src attribute)
    var $imgs = this.find('img[src!=""]');
    // if there's no images, just return an already resolved promise
    if (!$imgs.length) {return $.Deferred().resolve().promise();}

    // for each image, add a deferred object to the array which resolves when the image is loaded (or if loading fails)
    var dfds = [];  
    $imgs.each(function(){
        var dfd = $.Deferred();
        dfds.push(dfd);
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function(){dfd.resolve();}
        img.onerror = function(){dfd.resolve();}  //si alguna falla pq esta mal la url continua
        img.src = this.src;
    });
    // return a master promise object which will resolve when all the deferred objects have resolved
    // IE - when all the images are loaded
    return $.when.apply($,dfds);
}
```

Comment: Debieras marcar esta como la respuesta aceptada. :)

Answer (score 0):

Lo único que se me ocurre es que derives el `$('#divDrchoInteriores').removeClass("transparente");`  a una funcion

Tu funcion quedaría así

```js
function BuscarInteriores(numpage) {
  var formato=$("#selFormatoInterior option:selected").val();
  var tamaño=$("#selTamañoInterior option:selected").val();
  $.ajax({
       url: 'consultas/BuscarInterioresCondicionR.php',
       type: 'get',
       data:{'formato':formato,'tamaño':tamaño,'page':numpage},
       success: function (results) {
      $('#divDrchoInteriores').addClass("transparente"); 
      $('#divDrchoInteriores').html(results); /*para que no se vea antes de redimensionar*/
      /*Aquí debemos hacer un bucle recorriendo los results */
      numImagenesTotales = results.length;
      for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
           var html = '<img id="miId' + i + '" src=""/>'; 
           $("miId"+ i).bind('load', function() {
                actualizarContador(1);
           });

           $('#divDrchoInteriores').html($('#divDrchoInteriores').html()+html);
      } 
          },
       error: function(err){
        alert(err);
       }
   });
 }`
```

Y las funciones axiliares irían aquí

```js
var numImagenesTotales;
var numImgCargadas;

//Ir asociando esete evento a cada imagen
$("img").bind('load', function() {
    actualizarContador(1);
});

function actualizarContador(var num) {
    numImgCargadas = numImgCargadas + num;
    if(numImagenesTotales == numImgCargadas) {
            //Aqui ya sabes que todas las imagenenes están cargadas
            AsignarEventosaInteriores();
            AjustarAlturaImagenesInterior();
            AjustarAlturaCuadroImagenesInterior();
            $('#divDrchoInteriores').removeClass("transparente");
    }
}
```

PAra esta solución ess muy probable que necesites cambiar los que devuelve consultas/BuscarInterioresCondicionR.php a un json

Comment: Muchas gracias.Me quedo con la idea pero en este caso me es más complicado porque tendría que cambiar lo que estoy devolviendo en la variable results, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías utilizar un [promise](http://api.jquery.com/promise/) para la función `html()`:

```
$('#divDrchoInteriores').html(results).promise().done(function(){

  //código de cálculo de la altura

});
```

Un post (en inglés) que habla sobre el tema [aquí](https://digitizor.com/jquery-html-callback-function-using-promise/).

Comment: Muchas gracias Adrian, pero esta solución no me ha valido. Parece que no espera realmente a que se carguen todas las imágenes.